# Is it possible convert file .sql (I use MSSQL SERVER 2008 R2) to .bacpac with C# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure

I'm making an app (asp.net but not MVC) for deploy a project to windows azure, it works fine, but now I need export the local database to windows azure without use windows azure portal and for that I have to convert this file (.sql) to .bacpac, but I don't know how can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe... but you can just export your database as a Data Tier Application which should create a .bacpac file, or you can use the [SQL Azure Migration Wizard](https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) to help you move your application.

Comment: I use MSSQLSERVER 2008 R2, and I only can just export as a dacpac with Data Tier Application with Managment Studio, but I will try with SQL AZure Migration Wizard, thanks.

Comment: Finally I have installed Management Studio 2012 for I make that.

Answer (score 0):

Find your happiness in this article named : **How to Use Data-Tier Application Import and Export with Windows Azure SQL Database**

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2639.how-to-use-data-tier-application-import-and-export-with-windows-azure-sql-database-en-us.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you have an SQL Database project in Visual Studio, you can compile it as a dacpac file. (A dacpac can be used for both new deployments and for upgrade deployments.)

(An SQL Database project lets you define all schema definitions as SQL files.)

Comment: thanks for that, but I'm beginner in asp.net and C#, and I need upload to azure bacpa file which has schema and data database, so how can I do that like you say me?